# Python - pip install not found matching version

Tags: python, linux, centos, pip, python-2.6

I have a machine in CentOS 6.9 which for various reasons I am forced to use, with python2.6.6 . When I try to download a library with pip I try:

```
sudo -E pip install someLibrary
```

and I get for pandas for example

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for pandas

I suspect that it has to do with the version of python I use and that the repositories have been moved or whatever. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install someLibrary
…
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

Hehe, failed obfuscation. :-))) Next time try harder… if you don't want an answer…

Well, [pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas) doesn't support Python 2.6, only 2.7+.

[Version 0.17.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.17.1) seems to be the last one that supported Python 2.6. Install with pip

```
pip install pandas==0.17.1
```

or from [sources](https://pypi.python.org/packages/a9/8e/034d108c2b2834ad4cc5bf7fb2b4d96bacf135034a2e2d946f7b4661d461/pandas-0.17.1.tar.gz#md5=1e18b9a5496ec92752b3cb6674bbe987).

Comment: I wrote someLibrary because it is the same result for all libraries. Also with pandas==0.17.1 I get the same error. Can you briefly explain how to find the suitable version of a library for python 2.6. ?

Comment: There are no precompiled binaries for Python 2.6 for Linux (there are older versions for w32). Download [pandas-0.17.1.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/a9/8e/034d108c2b2834ad4cc5bf7fb2b4d96bacf135034a2e2d946f7b4661d461/pandas-0.17.1.tar.gz) and compile from sources.